# Wordpress divi HTML Inline pictures

Tags: html, css, wordpress

how to put 2 pictures next to each other? Must I use CSS or can it be HTML as well?

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <style>
 a:link { color: #D83F33; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: none; } 
 a:visited { color: #D83F33; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: none; } 
 a:hover { color: #D83F33; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: underline; } 
 a:active { color: #D83F33; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: underline; } 
 </style>
 <div align="center">
 <div class=nav1"> 
 <img src="https://reflex-jam.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Bootcamp-tekst.jpg" alt="E-Sportkleding" /> 
 <p> <a href="https://www.e-sportkleding.nl/html/" target="_blank" style="D83F33">E-sportkleding</a> </p> 
 <img src="https://www.trias-groep.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/logo_norm.png" alt="Trias" /> 
 <p> <a href="http://www.trias-groep.nl" target="_blank" style="D83F33">Trias jeugdhulp</a> </p> 
 </div> 
 </html> 
 </div>
```

This is my code right now. Who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Please modify html/css like in below snippet for putting pictures next to each other,Put img & p inside div please see below snippet in which i have edited html & added css in .nav1 to get desired result.

```css
 a:link { color: #D83F33; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: none; } 
 a:visited { color: #D83F33; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: none; } 
 a:hover { color: #D83F33; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: underline; } 
 a:active { color: #D83F33; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: underline; } 
.nav1{display:inline-block;padding:10px;text-align:center;}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <div>
 <div class="nav1"> 
 <img src="https://www.trias-groep.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/logo_norm.png" alt="E-Sportkleding" /> 
 <p> <a href="https://www.e-sportkleding.nl/html/" target="_blank" style="D83F33">E-sportkleding</a> </p> 
 </div> 
 <div class="nav1"> 
 <img src="https://www.trias-groep.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/logo_norm.png" alt="Trias" /> 
 <p> <a href="http://www.trias-groep.nl" target="_blank" style="D83F33">Trias jeugdhulp</a> </p> 
 
 </div> 
 </div> 
 </html>
```

Comment: i have edited it, when you check snippet its easy to get what i have modified in html/css so explaination was not needed there. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

wrap your `img` and `p` inside another `div` like these:

```
 <div class="nav1">
 <div>
 <img src="https://reflex-jam.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Bootcamp-tekst.jpg " alt="E-Sportkleding " />
 <p> <a href="https://www.e-sportkleding.nl/html/ " target="_blank " style="D83F33 ">E-sportkleding</a> </p>
 </div>
 <div>
 <img src="https://www.trias-groep.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/logo_norm.png " alt="Trias " />
 <p> <a href="http://www.trias-groep.nl " target="_blank " style="D83F33 ">Trias jeugdhulp</a> </p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

then add this to your css or `<style>` tag:

```
.nav1 div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Worked, but how to give a little more space between them?

Comment: @BrianSol you can add margin-right inside the .nav1 div{}